# How to write a function that takes function output as input for dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
from service.get_data import get_all_data


def get_by_stores_dept_id(argument1, argument2):
   result = get_all_cities_data(argument1, argument2)
   # Now I want to pass the the result as input parameter to pd 
   df = pd.DataFrame.?(result)
```

Here in this line I am passing the output result as to pandas dataframe. The return type of result is json.

```
# Now I want to pass the the result as input parameter to pd 
   df = pd.DataFrame.?(result)
```

I tried with  pd.DataFrame.**from_dict**(result) but no output

I tried in JUPYTER console but it is giving zero/no output. I dont understand which function of pandas to use. Any suggestion

Comment: If the type of 'result' is a json string, you have to parse it as a dict first (`result = json.loads(result)`). After that you should be able to create a dataframe from it. Can you post an excerpt of the result value?

Comment: Depends on what the `result` looks like. For example, if it's a list of dicts, you can just use `df = pd.DataFrame(result)`